# How to combine django-modeltranslation and django-reversion apps?

Tags: python, django, django-1.11, django-reversion, django-modeltranslation

**Question**: how to combine [django-modeltranslation](https://github.com/deschler/django-modeltranslation) and [django-reversion](https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion) apps?

I have next problem: in `models.py` file I registered `Slide` model which has `head` field. This field has several other fields for translation like `head_ru`, `head_kz`, `head_en`. I set these fields in `translation.py` and `settings.py` files. In DB slide table has all this fields. Also I show all this fields in form where user can edit data. When user submit the form django-reversion create version only for head field and ignore other fields. How to fix this problem?

**models.py:**

```
from django.db import models
import reversion

@reversion.register()
class Slide(models.Model):
    head = models.CharField(verbose_name='Title', max_length=200, blank=False,)
```

**translation.py:**

```
from modeltranslation.translator import TranslationOptions
from modeltranslation.translator import translator
from .models import Slide

class SlideTranslationOptions(TranslationOptions):
    fields = ('head',)

translator.register(Slide, SlideTranslationOptions)
```

**settings.py:**

```
LANGUAGES = (
    ('ru', 'Russian'),
    ('en', 'English'),
    ('kz', 'Kazakh'),
)
```

**views.py:**

```
class SlideEditView(RevisionMixin, UpdateView):
    template_name = 'slider/edit_slide.html'
    form_class = SlideForm
    model = Slide

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        data = dict()
        data['form_is_valid'] = True
        context = {'slides': Slide.objects.all(),}
        data['html_slides'] = render_to_string('slider/slides.html', context)
        reversion.set_comment('EDIT')
        return JsonResponse(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found solution:

```
@reversion.register(fields=['head', 'head_ru', 'head_en', 'head_kz',])
```